# Error while debugging Python in Visual Code Studio - Module not found

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, error-handling, installation, pysimplegui

I am facing trouble whilst trying to build a programme for my university's programming class. We are trying to programme an interactive database.

While trying to debug the code on Visual Studio Code, I get the following error:

```
No module named 'PySimpleGUI'
  File "C:\Users\luka\Desktop\Programming\Programming_Project.py", line 3, in <module>
    import PySimpleGUI as sg
```

I am trying to run a programme that runs both PySimpleGui, as well as an adaptor for postgresql. The adaptor is called psycopg2. I have installed both of them successfully through the Command Prompt. Nonetheless, I keep getting the problem over and over again.

Could anyone give me any suggestions on what could be done here to solve this issue?

Comment: Sounds like you installed via the command line and then are running a virtual environment in your visual studio setup.  You'll need to install from within Visual Studio.  I use PyCharm so not sure how to instruct you exactly how to do it.

Comment: How did you install your dependencies via Command Prompt? And is the environment you selected in VS Code match the one you installed your dependencies into?